# Retrieving related model of a deleted model in Prisma 2

Tags: prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma, prisma2

Hello guys here is the scenario i have;

```
model User {
  id              Int               @default(autoincrement()) @id
  ...
  posts           Post[]
  comments        Comment[]
  
}
model Post {
  id          Int            @default(autoincrement()) @id
  comments    Comment[]
  ...
  
}
model Comment {
  id          Int               @default(autoincrement()) @id
  post        Post              @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId      Int
  ...
}
```

So i'm trying to delete a comment, and below is my approach

```
export const deleteComment = mutationField('deleteComment', {
    type: 'Comment',
    args: {
        where: 'CommentWhereUniqueInput',
    },
    resolve: async (_, { where }, ctx) => {
        let comment = await ctx.prisma.comment.delete({
            where: where,
            include:{
                author: true,
                post:true
            },
        })
      
        return comment
    },
})
```

But i'm having an error message which says 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Comment.post.'
Any idea how i can solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with npm i @paljs/plugins

https://paljs.com/plugins/delete/
or https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database-workflows/cascading-deletes/postgresql